# Parse error on input "="

Tags: haskell

Hi i'm getting a (Line 7) Parse error in input "=" for this which just sums the words in a string, any help is appreciated. Thanks.

```
module Main where

main = do
 putStr "Enter a string: "
 input <- getContents

 value = unwords . sum . words input
 putStrLn (value)
```

Comment: If you write "let" in front of value, the syntax error will go away, and you can get on with the type errors. It is not obvious to me what it means to sum the words in any old string, or why one could sensibly `unwords` the result of doing so. Can you give an example of what you want to happen?

Comment: Ah I confused myself after using unwords most of the time when using words. What I expect to happen is for input to be e.g "this is a string" and words splits it to ["this", "is", "a", "string"] then sum would count these and store the number in value, which would then be printed. Is sum the correct function for this? Cheers.

Comment: No, `sum` computes the sum of a list of numbers. If you want to count the words, you can just use `length` to get the length of the list, followed by `show` to make a string from the length. Or you can just use `print` instead of `putStrLn` to display a number.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line:

```
value = unwords . sum . words input
```

Is not syntactically valid.  You need a let statement.

```
let value = unwords . sum . words input
```

This still isn't valid, you want to apply your function (well, composition of three functions) to the input:

```
let value = (unwords . sum . words) input
```

or perhaps:

```
let value = unwords . sum . words $ input
```

This still isn't valid because the input is a `String` and the result of `words` is a list of `String` (`[String]`).  So you'll want to read the strings into some `Num` type (`Integer`s?) then convert back to `String`.  `unwords` is not useful because you only have one word, the sum, left at the end (vs a list of words, which unwords would need):

```
let value = show . sum . map read. words $ input
```

Depending on the type, you might want to annotate the read or the sum to specify if it's an `Int` or a `Double` or something else.

Comment: Thanks! I'm not entirely sure about how read works and why you would need to map read onto a list of strings, could you explain that a little more?

Comment: Well, you can't sum a list of strings, since you can't add strings.

Comment: You comments to pigworker suggest you are looking for `length`.  I assumed you wanted the total of a list of numbers - `sum` will add up a list of numbers.  `read` takes a string and turns it into a number (`map read` will just do the same for a list of strings to a list of numbers).